# How to play more than one audio file in the same page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, audio

I have a chat page where a user can send texts, images, audio and video as messages to the other users. Everything works fine except for the Audio and Video. In my chat application, a user is allowed to pick audio files using the file_picker plugin. After the user picks an audio file, it is then uploaded to a server. The server than sends back the audio file using a socket event. My app listens to the socket event and generates the message view depending on the type of messages. If its a text message, it is shown in a text widget. If its a audio message, it is shown in an audio widget. audio_player plugin is used to play the audio file. When the user uploads an audio, after a little time the audio file is shown to both the users chatting in the same room. Everything works fine if it is a single audio file. If the user uploads another audio file as in a 2nd audio, the audio controller replaces all my audio files in the chat view with the last audio uploaded. The code used for audio is below:

```
    //for audio files (This code has been placed in _ChatPageState)
  AnimationController _animationIconController1;
  AudioCache audioCache;
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
  Duration _duration = new Duration();
  Duration _position = new Duration();
  Duration _slider = new Duration(seconds: 0);
  double durationValue;
  bool isSongPlaying = false;
  bool isPlaying = false;
```

Later, the variables are initialsed in initState()

```
//for audio inside initState
_position = _slider;
_animationIconController1 = AnimationController(
  vsync: this,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 750),
  reverseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 750),
);
audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
audioCache = new AudioCache(fixedPlayer: audioPlayer);
audioPlayer.durationHandler = (d) => setState(() {
  _duration = d;
});

audioPlayer.positionHandler = (p) => setState(() {
  _position = p;
});
```

Next, if the user receives a audio file from socket listener an audio widget is presented, so that the users can play the file:

```
Widget audioMessage(int index) {
return Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
  height: 30,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            isPlaying ? _animationIconController1.reverse() : _animationIconController1.forward();
            isPlaying = !isPlaying;
          });
          // Add code to pause and play the music.
          if (!isSongPlaying){
            audioPlayer.play('some hidden link/file/${messages[index].message}');
            setState(() {
              isSongPlaying = true;
            });
          } else {
            audioPlayer.pause();
            setState(() {
              isSongPlaying = false;
            });
          }
        },
        child: ClipOval(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.pink[600],
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: AnimatedIcon(
                icon: isSongPlaying ==false ? AnimatedIcons.play_pause : AnimatedIcons.pause_play,
                size: 14,
                progress: _animationIconController1,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Slider(
        activeColor: Colors.white,
        inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
        value: _position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
        max: _duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
        onChanged: (double value) {
          seekToSeconds(value.toInt());
          value = value;
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

I think the problem is with my audio and animation controllers. It is only initiated for only one player. So how can i go around this problem. A user can upload as many audios as he wants. How can i dynamically create audio controllers for as many audio files that are uploaded by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have accomplished this by moving all my audio codes into a separate dart file. See below for audio implementation:

```
  class PlayAudio extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  
  const PlayAudio({Key key, this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlayAudioState createState() => _PlayAudioState();
}

class _PlayAudioState extends State<PlayAudio> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  //for audio files
  AnimationController _animationIconController1;
  AudioCache audioCache;
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
  Duration _duration = new Duration();
  Duration _position = new Duration();
  Duration _slider = new Duration(seconds: 0);
  double durationValue;
  bool isSongPlaying = false;
  bool isPlaying = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    //for audio inside initState
    _position = _slider;
    _animationIconController1 = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 750),
      reverseDuration: new Duration(milliseconds: 750),
    );
    audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
    audioCache = new AudioCache(fixedPlayer: audioPlayer);
    audioPlayer.durationHandler = (d) => setState(() {
      _duration = d;
    });

    audioPlayer.positionHandler = (p) => setState(() {
      _position = p;
    });

    print('audio widget: ' + widget.url);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    audioPlayer.dispose();
  }

  void seekToSeconds(int second) {
    Duration newDuration = Duration(seconds: second);
    audioPlayer.seek(newDuration);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
      height: 30,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isPlaying ? _animationIconController1.reverse() : _animationIconController1.forward();
                isPlaying = !isPlaying;
              });
              // Add code to pause and play the music.
              if (!isSongPlaying){
                audioPlayer.play('${widget.url}');
                setState(() {
                  isSongPlaying = true;
                });
              } else {
                audioPlayer.pause();
                setState(() {
                  isSongPlaying = false;
                });
              }
            },
            child: ClipOval(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.pink[600],
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: AnimatedIcon(
                    icon: AnimatedIcons.play_pause,
                    size: 14,
                    progress: _animationIconController1,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Slider(
            activeColor: Colors.white,
            inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
            value: _position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
            max: _duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
            onChanged: (double value) {
              seekToSeconds(value.toInt());
              value = value;
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is now a separate class. Now, to play multiple audio files all I am doing is calling the above file into my main.dart wherever it is needed. Make sure you call 'new' everytime you want to play a new audio file, just pass an url. See below:

```
new PlayAudio(url: 'some URL');
```

Hope this helps to play multiple audio files in the same page. FYI, i am using https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

Comment: Does it mean that it will create a separate audio player for each audio sent/received instead of using only one audio player for the chat page? I think this approach will cause an issue where audio players are stacked upon each other.

Comment: Yes it will create a seperate audio player for each sent/received audio files. It is important in a chat page where users send multiple voice recordings. If you do not seperate it, when you play a single file, all files will be played at the same time and you will also face problem seeking forward.